# Install v8js in fedora error with GNU_UNIQUE

Tags: php, gnu, pecl

I recently read about v8js and php server side rendering. I tried installing it via pecl, It told me that my v8 version is 3.14 and 3.24 is required.  I tried installing older v8js-0.1.4, which required 3.17 at minimum. DNF repo only have 3.14 of libv8 so I searched and found http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Platform6/srpms/v8-3.24 . When I tried to install it, I am getting this error.

```
[Abhinav@abhinav-fed22 geny] $ sudo dnf install ./libv8-3.24-3.24.35.33-alt0.M60P.1.x86_64.rpm 
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:15:14 ago on Sat Jun 27 12:54:33 2015.
Error: nothing provides rtld(GNU_UNIQUE) needed by libv8-3.24-3.24.35.33-alt0.M60P.1.x86_64
```

I looked for GNU_UNIQUE but could not find anything.  I even found another site with rpm for V8-3.24 but it gave same error.

How do I install V8-3.24 and thus install v8js php extension on Fedora 22.